# Probability Generating Function Property for positive random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

N assumes positive ($N\geq0$) integers and $g_N(t)$ is the probability generating function of N.

How can I show that $\frac{g_N(t) - 1}{t-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N>t)*t^k, |t|<1$?

Comment: Did you try to simplify $$(t-1)\cdot\sum_kP(N>k)t^k\ ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Since the support for $N$ is the non-negative integers.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(N>k)t^k ~=~ & \sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k \sum_{h=1+k}^\infty \mathsf P(N=h) \\[1ex] ~=~& \sum_{h=1}^\infty P(N=h)\sum_{k=0}^{h-1}t^k \\[1ex] \ddots &\end{align}$$